# What does this sed line do?

Tags: sed

I am not familiar with `sed`. Now I came accross the following line in a shell script:

```
sed 's|'`pwd`'||'
```

what does the line do? Does it replace `||` with something else?

Comment: no. `|` is the pattern delimiter. it's replacing whatever the output of `pwd` is, with nothing.

Comment: Even though it is intended to change the output of `pwd` to nothing, this will actually not do anything. It will just sit and wait. `sed` expects an input from STDIN or file which I don't see specified here, unless you have truncated that portion.

Comment: I have turncated that portion, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @mrsteve No problem. The reason for using `|` as the delimiter is because output from `pwd` usually consists of one or more `/`. As though would conflict with `/` delimiters commonly used with `sed`, it is often preferred to use a different set of delimiters instead of escaping `/` which obviously can't be done here.

Comment: can someone write an answer and I quickly accept it? so it's answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it removes any string that equals to `current-working-directory` in the input. because pwd may itself contain `/` instead of `/`, `|` used in `sed` command as pattern-delimiter.